# AsymptoticSolve for Taylor Expansion of Implicit Function

Tags: implicit, asymptotics

I have an implicit function

```
FullFunc[m_, \[Alpha]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 2 Exp[\[Beta]*\[Alpha]^2 (m*Coth[\[Beta]*m] - 1)] Sinh[\[Beta]*
      m]/(1 + 2 Exp[\[Beta]*\[Alpha]^2 (m*Coth[\[Beta]*m] - 
           1)] Cosh[\[Beta]*m]) - m
```

where I am finding values of (m, alpha, beta) where FullFunc(m, alpha, beta) = 0. Note that m=0 is a solution for all alpha, beta.

I would like to find Taylor expansions of the implicit functions f(a,b) and g(m) such that FullFunc(f(a,b), a, b)=0 and FullFunc(m, g(m))=0 (here we need to exclude m=0). I want to do this around the point (alpha,beta)=(0.800354,1.87676). Note that there is an area of values of alpha, beta for which m=0 is the only solution to our implicit function, so I need to find a way of excluding that line or just excluding the m=0 solution in general.

However, I believe I am doing something wrong with the syntax. I have tried

```
AsymptoticSolve[FullFunc[m, a, b] == 0, {m, 0}, {{a, b}, {0.800354, 1.87676}, {5, 5}}]
```

This returns empty brackets. I'm guessing this is because {0.800354, 1.87676} is only approximate.

In the other direction, I have tried

```
AsymptoticSolve[FullFunc[m, a, b] == 0, {{a, b}, {0.800354, 1.87676}}, {m, 0, 5}]
```

But this returns the code, not a solution. I'm probably doing something wrong with the syntax here or there is a problem because of the m=0 solution. However, changing the m value to something slightly higher doesn't return anything either. I haven't figured out how to only look at nonzero m values.

I suspect I am missing something fundamental about this Mathematica tool. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems that you have a hint about numbers not being exact. Have you tried `{Rationalize@0.800354, Rationalize@1.87676}`?

Comment: It's not working, unfortunately. Still getting empty brackets as a response from Mathematica